# install multiple python modules through a script

Tags: python, module

I have .tar files of multiple python modules and need to install these modules in a sequence.
with the bash, I can simply iterate the directories one by one, and execute python setup.py install command.
but how to do the same with a python script. I am not able to iterate directories in Python script.

the sample bash commands are like :-

```
sudo yum upgrade python-setuptools;
cd setuptools_scm-4.1.2;
/usr/bin/python setup.py install;
cd ../importlib_metadata-1.6.1;
/usr/bin/python setup.py install;
cd ../configparser-4.0.2;
/usr/bin/python setup.py install;
```

Comment: generate the requirements file from pip freeze. then you can easily do like pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: I do not have the access to outer network, so not able to execute pip command

Answer (score 0):

You can install packages listed in a text file called requirements file. For example, if you have a file called requirements.txt containing the required modules that's needed to be installed. You can install them by using:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I don't have the connectivity to the outer network to use pip. I need to install from tar ball only.